# Alpha decay, why does it occur?

Tags: radiation, atoms, strong-force

I was reading about alpha decay and why it happens.

The strong force holds protons and neutrons together, but I don't get why does an atom emit helium nucleus when it has too many protons&neutrons? I mean why isn't the strong force holding on to it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are alpha particles such a prominent form of radiation and not other types of nucleon arrangement?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61699/)

Comment: No, I don't think it explains what I'm asking about. I read it and didn't found the answer to my question.

Comment: The answer to "Why---I mean *really* **why**---does [something quantum mechanical] occur?" is always *"Because it can"*. The Totalitarian Rule is always present in the quantum realm.

Comment: My question is "why isn't the strong force holding on to it?". You can't just say lets it go "Because it can".

Comment: The condition with the alpha *in* the nucleus is allowed (by energy concerns), but so it the condition with it *out* of the nucleus. Allowed conditions are mandatory and all that remains is to compute the rate.

Comment: @zoran404, quantum tunnelling processes, such as radioactive decay, have no classical counterpart.  I think you may be trying to reason classically here rather than quantum mechanically.  Quantum particles can overcome potential barriers, via tunnelling, that classical particles cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is because it becomes more stable by emitting alpha particle (or any other kind of decay).

Nuclei become more stable once their proton & neutron count is close to "stability islands" which are just "magic" numbers that atoms are more stable when their proton & neutron number gets close to them.

The reason behind why these islands exists can't be explained easily, and to some extent they arise from different theoretical models of the nucleus, which in general are almost impossible to be modeled accurately (this info is kinda outdated and from an old book, maybe today with fast computers the situation is different).

Comment: Ok, but will another alpha decay occur if the atom is still far from one of those numbers?

Comment: Yes of course! it can happen multiple times! but the closer it to the islands, the longer it will take to produce another decay.